# Regex to validate logical && || operators in string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am trying to create a Regex expression to validate logical `&&` `||` string combonation and its corresponding  opening and closing `()` brackets.

I have been messing with the Regex hieroglyphic pattern but can't seem to get it working correctly, mainly due to my complete lack of understanding of the Regex pattern.

After several hours of StackOverflow and google this is what I have so far, I feel I am close.

```
    private void ValidationTest()
    {
        string hieroglyphics = @"^(?=^[^()]*\((?>[^()]+|\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>))*(?(DEPTH)(?!))\)[^()]*$)[(]*\d+[)]*(\s+(&&|\|\|)\s+[(]*\d+[)]*)*$";

        var tests = new List<string>
        {
            // Working
             "(1 && 2)",
             "((1 && 2) && (3 || 4))",
             "((1 && 2) && (3 || 4) || ((1 && 2) && (3 || 4)))",

            // Not working
            "(Stack && Overflow)"
        };

        if (tests.All(test => Regex.IsMatch(test, hieroglyphics)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Woohoo!!");
        }
    }
```

So the main issue with what I have so far is if ther are no brackets `1 && 2` it wont validate, same with `(1 && 2) && (3 || 4)`.
Also it seems to ignore words alltogeter `(Stack && Overflow)`

Examples of some strings I am tring to validate.

```
"IsRecording && IsPlaying"
"IsVisible && (IsPlaying && (IsMusic || IsRadio))"
```

There is also some keywords that contain brakets that could mess things up
Example:

```
"IsWindowVisible(2) && (IsControlVisible(22) && IsControlFocused(100))"
```

**Edit:**
As it is now this expression works fine validating the kind of complexity I need, however the only real issue I have is that its nubers only.

Complex example that validates fine with this `Regex`

```
"((1 && 2) && (3 || 4) || ((1 && 2) && (3 || 4)))"
```

A simple string `1 && 2` wont validate without brakets, but I dont mind adding brackest to these.

all I need is to add support for words instead of just numbers, this will be a fixed list of words if that helps.

If someone can spot the error or point me in a better direction would be awesome
Thanks

### Edit:

Answer by [mellamokb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116614/mellamokb) worked perfect. It seems the trouble was the `d+` needed to be `0-9a-zA-Z()`

Here is the pattern incase it usefull for anyone else.

```
   string hieroglyphics = @"^(?=^[^()]*(?>[^()]+|\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>))*(?(DEPTH)(?!))[^()]*$)[(]*[0-9a-zA-Z()]+[)]*(\s+(&&|\|\|)\s+[(]*[0-9a-zA-Z()]+[)]*)*$";
```

it validates exactly what I need

Examples:

```
 "IsPlayer(Video) && Player(Playing)",
 "((IsPlayer(Video) && (Player(Playing) && ControlIsVisible(34))) || (IsPlayer(Video) && (Player(Playing) && ControlIsVisible(34)))) && ControlIsFocused(22)"
```

Comment: The "regular" in "regular expression" refers to the restricted class of languages that a regex can accept, the simplest (not totally inaccurate) description of which is that they correspond to a finite state machine that can not count. So it is impossible in true regexp languages to match brackets to arbitrary depth.

Comment: This problem cannot be solved with regular expressions, unless your input string is limited to a fixed number of nested bracket depth. You cannot do it with regex if you want to support indefinite number of nested parentheses. For this you need to write a small custom parser.

Comment: I agree with @SinaIravanian, this is not a problem that a regex can solve. Look into writing a parser and/or grammar. I've actually done something very similar for this same problem and it worked out nicely.

Comment: The sting is compiled in another application using `CodeDom` at the moment I am using the same `CodeDom` method to validate, as you could imagine its pretty slow/stupid, I was just hoping for a simple `Regex` solution, I dont mind setting a depth limit on the nested brakets if it would be possible to use `Regex` or does the amount of nested braket pairs have to be the same for every string?

Comment: What about balancing group definitions? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition

Comment: @David That description is actually pretty accurate (well, the consequence is). What’s your gripe with it? That it implies counting to infinity? (Not that this strictly matters here, .NET “regex” *can* count.)

Comment: @Beaner, as it is my regex works it just won't accept letters only numbers, I can live with adding the extra bracket needed around simple expressions `1 && 2` as the `CodeDom` compiler wont care. but its just the number only thing I am stuck with.

Comment: What's the end goal here? Is it to parse an expression from a string and apply it to an object instance?

Comment: @Russ Cam, I have a custom skinnable GUI solution, and It has a skin editor application, the skin editor can build a "VisibleCondition" for a control, This string is complied at startup of the GUI application, I just wanted to add some sort validation as some users may struggle with the `&&` `||` '()' combonation. all I need is words to be accepted in the regex

Comment: @David Carlisle, you said `it is impossible in true regexp languages to match brackets to arbitrary depth` but I can't seem to make this fail, at what point wont this work, My `RegEx` seems to handle any number of nested `()` that I give, I even made a few strings with 30+ nested `()` and it still works fine.

Comment: @sa_ddam213: He is right that strict regular language cannot describe bracket matching. But you are also right since C# regular expression (it is NOT strictly regular) supports bracket matching construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason you are not able to validate expressions without a wrapping `()` is the wrapping parentheses in your core nesting logic.  If you take out the following parentheses I note below, then the other two non-wrapped expressions validate:

```
^(?=^[^()]*\((?>[^()]+|\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>))*(?(DEPTH)(?!))\)[^()]*$...
           ^^ remove this                            remove this ^^
```

Then in order to allow expressions that are not just numerical, you need to replace your restrictive `\d` with a more liberal definition of what you want to validate, say, `[0-9a-zA-Z]`:

```
...[(]*\d+[)]*(\s+(&&|\|\|)\s+[(]*\d+[)]*)*$
       ^^ change these expression ^^
```

So it would become:

```
...[(]*[0-9a-zA-Z]+[)]*(\s+(&&|\|\|)\s+[(]*[0-9a-zA-Z]+[)]*)*$
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/jwkcpL