# RegEx to split string based on operators and retain operator in answer

Tags: java, regex, string, split, pattern-matching

I want to split string based on few operands.

For e.g.
String : **a&&(b||c)**

ANS : String[] **{a,&&,(,||,c,)}**

IS it possible with java RegEx? If yes then how?

I tried with **[&&||()]** regEx , but its not giving desired output. and even I am not sure how to retain operators.

**EDIT:**
And what if we have & and | instead of && and || ?

Comment: please be more specific.

Comment: @ Zagorulkin Dmitry  : i want to split input string and answer should be as shown above.

Comment: The answer is: Yes, it is possible. Maybe you're really asking "How do I do it?" In which case: show us what you've done and what the result was, tell us what you expected the result to be, and we'll tell you what to change.

Comment: It would rather parse it.

Comment: But in your example, you're not distinguishing between operators and other tokens. You just need a regex that will match any token, whether it be an operator or something else.

Comment: I am not sure about that this bellow link can help you
[Regex to validate logical && || operators in string][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718556/regex-to-validate-logical-operators-in-string

Answer (score 4):

You could split by:

```
(?<![&|])(?=[&|])|(?<=[&|])(?![&|])
```

- `(?<![&|])(?=[&|])` means "any *inter-char* that **isn't** preceded by `&` or `|` but that **is** followed by `&` or `|`";
- On the opposit, `(?<=[&|])(?![&|])` means "any *inter-char* that **is** preceded by `&` or `|` but that **isn't** followed by `&` or `|`".

For example:

```java
String pattern = "(?<![&|])(?=[&|])|(?<=[&|])(?![&|])";
String input = "a&&(b||c)";
String[] array = input.split(pattern);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Prints:

```
[a, &&, (b, ||, c)]
```

Comment: And what if we have & and | instead of && and || ? will above would work?

Comment: @PriyankDoshi Just try it `:)` (Spoiler: yes)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a list of "operands", e.g.:

`[0-9]|[a-z]|[A-Z]|\|\||&&|\(|\)`

Each non-escaped `|` defines new operand. You need to escape some operands which are keywords by adding `\`.

Then you need to use `find` of `java.util.regex.Matcher`. to get each operand.