# Regular expression to split string based on logical operator

Tags: java, regex, split

I have an expression like this

```
String x = ".pyValue='2||3'||.pxValue='5'"
```

I want to split this string based on logical operators like "and" and "or" using a regular expression.

```
String a = ".pyValue='2||3'"
String b = ".pxValue='5'"
```

or string could be like this

```
String x = ".pyValue='2||3'||.pxValue='2' && .pxValue=3 && .pxValue='2&&3'"
```

Output should be like this

```
String a = ".pyValue='2||3'"
String b = ".pxValue='2'"
String c = ".pxValue=3"
String d = ".pxValue='2&&3'"
```

Comment: Regex is not a good tool for parsing text with nested syntax like string literals. Use a parser, not regex.

Comment: Rather than giving examples, can you also give **exact logic** for splitting that needs to be implemented?

Comment: As mentioned above, I need to split by || or && (logical operator). 
for example 
`String x = ".pyValue='2||3'||pxValue='5'"`

As per the logic the answer should be 2 strings
`String a = ".pyValue='2||3'"`
`String b = "pxValue='5'"`

here the problem is this the substring itself can contain logical operator

Comment: but && and || can also be within quotes as well, right?

Comment: yes  the substring itself can contain logical operator. Substring can start with any character. substring may contain single quote

Answer (score 0):

This regular can help you:

```
(?<=')\s?(\|{2}|\&{2})\s?
```

But you should to be careful with name of parameters, all of it must begin with a `.` character.

Using:

```
    String data = ".pyValue='2||3'||.pxValue='2' &| .pxValue=3 && .pxValue='2&&3'";

    String[] array = data.split("(?<=')\\s?(\\|{2}|\\&{2})\\s?");

    for(String string : array){
        System.out.println(string);
    }
```

Result:

```
.pyValue='2||3'
.pxValue='2'
.pxValue=3
.pxValue='2&&3'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. this works fine with the string starting with a dot(.)
what if the starting of the character may or may not contains a dot(.)?

Comment: For finding boolean operation in the `String` we must have a character, by which one can distinguish the boolean operation from value of paramters and between paramters. 
For example, if all of values will have a pipes `'`
The regular expresiton can be  `(?<=')\s?(\||\&){2}\s?`. It will spliting this String: `.pyValue='2||3'||.pxValue='2' && .pxValue='3' && .pxValue='2&&3'`

Comment: Also you can use this rexular expresion : `\s?(\||\&){2}\s?(?=\D)`. The first letter of parameter`s name can`t be a digit, so if the regex will find a boolean operation where the next character is not equal a digit, it will be matching

Comment: `(\||\&){2}` can match `||` and `&&`, but also `|&` and `&|`, which is certainly not correct.

Comment: Yes, you`re right. 
So the rigth regex must have: `(\&\&|\|\|)` or `(\&{2}|\|{2})`

Comment: Thanks BullyBoo and Andreas for your help.

Answer (score -1):

```
We've to provide list of 'Operands', for example 

    [0-9]|[a-z]|[A-Z]|\|\||&&|\(|\)

Each operand is separaed by '|', we can escape some operands which are keywords by adding \. 


For example:

String pattern = "(?<![&|])(?=[&|])|(?<=[&|])(?![&|])";


String input = "a&&(b||c)";
String[] array = input.split(pattern);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array));
Prints: [a, &&, (b, ||, c)]
```

For more info please look into it - [RegEx to split string based on operators and retain operator in answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105299/regex-to-split-string-based-on-operators-and-retain-operator-in-answer)

Comment: The point (problem) in the question is to *not* split on the first `||` because they are inside a string literal. Also, examples in question clearly show that OP doesn't want to keep the `||`.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry for my bad.