# Regular expression to validate logical operator expression in JS

Tags: javascript, c#

I have got the regular expression from [Regex to validate logical && || operators in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718556/regex-to-validate-logical-operators-in-string) to validate the logical operator expression in C#

```
"^(?=^[^()]*\((?>[^()]+|\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>))*(?(DEPTH)(?!))\)[^()]*$)[(]*\d+[)]*(\s+(&&|\|\|)\s+[(]*\d+[)]*)*$"
```

However I cannot use it as JS. Can anyone help me convert this regular expression to JS or share me any tool to convert RegExp from C# to JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly convert this into JS. .NET supports recursive regex and JS does not (and I'd argue against using this because it's impossible to read and maintain).

You'd be better off using a stack based parser for this (ie, a state machine). The problem isn't really any different from that of how you'd build a calculator (eg, how would you parse a string like "(1 + 2) * 3"?). You can find a simple parser like that [here](http://jorendorff.github.io/calc/docs/calculator-parser.html), for example.

Comment: Is there any resource to parse the string following postfix notation?